# Did breaking of discrete symmetries play a role in the development of steady-state cosmology?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology

If you look at the original pair of 1948 papers[Bondi 1948,Hoyle 1948] that proposed the steady-state model, it's clear that they knew they were throwing out a lot of cherished principles of physics. The Bondi paper in particular reads like a catalog of ideas to be given up: Lorentz invariance, the equivalence principle, possibly conservation of charge and mass-energy.

Although they clearly recognized that they were breaking Lorentz symmetry, there is no discussion of discrete symmetries. It seems that they were also violating time-reversal (T) and charge conjugation (C), and that they were violating CPT. The steady-state model persisted well into the 1960s, by which time I think the study of these discrete symmetries and their violation were more clearly understood by physicists to be at the core of their discipline.

Did anyone in either camp point out at some point that these breakings of discrete symmetries were present and possibly an important feature of the model?

I suppose that the CPT theorem is irrelevant, since the CPT theorem limits what you can do if you want to maintain Lorentz invariance, but they'd already broken Lorentz invariance. Hoyle and Narlikar didn't actually attempt to add dynamics to the theory by making it a quantum field theory (which, after all, would require Lorentz invariance). They instead tried to do it as a direct field theory.[Hoyle 1964]

Bondi and Gold, "The Steady-State Theory of the Expanding Universe," MNRAS 108 (1948) 252 http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=1948MNRAS.108..252B

Hoyle, "A New Model for the Expanding Universe," MNRAS 108 (1948) 372. http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=1948MNRAS.108..372H

Hoyle and Narlikar, "The C-field as a direct particle field," Proc Roy Soc London 282 (1964) 178